# USB A-B cable without Vcc

Tags: power-supply, usb, cables

I build a lot of my own devices, using a USB interface.  Many are self-powered, using either an on-board PSU (Power Supply Unit) module (linear or switching), or an off-board 5V PSU (or however many different voltages I happen to need). During testing, I often used a hacked-up cable, with the Vcc wire cut.  I don't like doing that (for obvious reasons) on the finished-product.  For the finished product, I simply leave the Vcc pin disconnected on the USB-B connector (I don't want the 5V PSU to fight the Vcc pin from my computer!)

Is it possible to *buy* a USB A-B cable that's missing Vcc?  I've searched, especially on Amazon, but all of the results are for regular USB cables.  In other posts, I've heard people talk about using special "red" cables, but I can't find any mention of those on the selling sites.  I only want to buy 2 or 3; not a bazillion!

Comment: If you weight in the production costs of a dedicated non-conformant cable that nobody needs with a [negative] cost of NOT routing the trace to the connector you'll probably answer the question yourself

Comment: What is the point of not just leaving the pin disconnected on your PCB? If it's troublesome to use a standard USB cable, you can bet on that you will create lots of trouble this way because users WILL use standard cables as well.

Comment: Since you're not connecting Vbus on your board I assume you're applying a pullup on D+ or D- as soon as your board has power. If so then FYI your devices are probably not USB-spec compliant. You're not supposed to apply any pullup resistors to D+ or D- to indicate the device speed until *after* the host supplies USB Vbus.

Comment: @brhans how many products actually follow that?

Comment: It is quite bad an engineering practice to rely on a standard-looking, but non-standard part, worse if the part is user-replaceable. The average user will plug in whatever USB cable they have available. It will not be their fault when something releases the blue smoke.

Comment: @Passerby - all of the ones for which  I've designed the hardware or written firmware ...

Comment: Such cables are an abomination.

Comment: Consider using a power-oring IC; they're cheap and avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to buy a USB A-B cable that's missing Vcc?

I'm reminded of an often heard saying from my youth, *"Yes, you can.  No, you may not."*

Such cables would violate the USB specification which means nobody that wants to retain good relations with many entities in the industry will be willing to produce such cables.

> I've searched, especially on Amazon, but all of the results are for regular USB cables.

Amazon, Google, and Apple went on something of a crusade years ago against USB products that didn't meet the USB specifications.  People were seeing some very expensive electronics go up in smoke because of non-compliant USB devices, and that was not reflecting well on them.  They cleared out non-compliant devices from their stores as best they could, made demands of suppliers to clean up their act, and this cleared out many of the worst violators.  I'm still seeing plenty of products on Amazon that break the USB spec in vary obvious ways so I'm surprised you can't find what you are looking for from someone.

> In other posts, I've heard people talk about using special "red" cables, but I can't find any mention of those on the selling sites. I only want to buy 2 or 3; not a bazillion!

They are likely talking about USB 3.x debug cables, they often have red connectors on the ends to denote their rather unique wiring.  Here's an example on what I hope remains a viable link: https://www.datapro.net/products/usb-3-0-super-speed-a-a-debugging-cable.html
These cables are USB-A to USB-A, not USB-A to USB-B, but they fit the description of a "red" USB cable that has the power pin unconnected.  They also have the USB 2.0 D+/D- pins unconnected, as required by the USB 3.x specification.  The cables connect ground and the "super speed" data lines for host-to-host communications.  They are called "debug" cables because the most common use is to provide a data link for software debugging.

It would be in your best interests, and that of your customers, not to violate the USB specifications on the USB products you design and build.

One suggestion I would like to make is have a captive USB-A cable on the device.  This means you can leave the +5 volt line unconnected without a cable that breaks the USB spec in very dangerous ways.  As I understand the spec leaving the +5 volt like unconnected is breaking the spec because the presence of voltage on the wire is part of the handshaking.  Perhaps I am mistaken.  What I am quite certain about though is that supplying voltage on a USB-B port is going to break something, and I don't mean just the USB specifications.  Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest easy to get to your end goal is on the PCB. Some Arduino Nano clones have two solder pads next to each other and you simply cut through the copper trace between the two pads.  The Teensey boards have a similar format. Check yours to see if this is done.

Some boards have a diode in series with the USB in before it reaches the regulator so you can connect power to the Arduino USB pin and use a standard USB cable. The diode prevents higher board voltage from reaching your computer's usb.

Mostly, check that he problem is not already solved for you or that a quick cut of a trace on the board is already designed in.  If it is your own board, design it in yourself. Good luck.